# How can I get rid of the lock, which is giving " Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process" as error

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

How can I get rid of the lock, which is giving " Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process" as error.when geth is running in another tab.

Comment: You can define a new data directory for the new geth client?

Answer (score 0):

restart the pc .. i have the same problem !